# How to connect JupyterLab to Django's models?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a JupyterLab called forecasting.ipynb in the same folder as manage.py and db.sqlite3. I want to connect to db.sqlite3 to access the models in models.py. I have a model called `Coin` and want to do `Coin.objects.all()` to access all my coins.

forecasting.ipynb:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Coin;'):
    print(row)

connection.close()
```

It says:

> OperationalError: no such table: Coin

I tried both `coin` and `COIN` but neither work. I'm confused because I have a model called `Coin` in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Coin(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10, unique=True)
    baseVolume = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    coin_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=50)
    coin_description = models.TextField(default="")
    # price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.ticker,self.baseVolume)
```

When I do `Coin.objects.all()` in tasks.py, it works. Is my syntax/code wrong or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: See [docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#table-names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#table-names).

Answer (score 0):

After running `pip install notebook django-extensions`, in settings.py set this variable to allow Jupyter to run queries:

```
DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE=True
```

You can then run `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`.